# Why does Cognito not return NewDeviceMetadata for CUSTOM_AUTH flow so that I can remember devices?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-js

When using the `CUSTOM_AUTH`  flow in Amplify SDK for React, even on a new device after `PASSWORD_VERIFIER` no `NewDeviceMetadata` is sent back thus preventing from marking the logged in device as remembered. The user pool has device tracking set to `Always`.

After a successful issuance of tokens when trying to perform `await Auth.rememberDevice()`, I am getting:

> Device tracking has not been configured in this user pool

```
Errors.ts:14 Uncaught (in promise) AuthError: Device tracking has not been configured in this User Pool
    at new AuthError (Errors.ts:14:1)
    at Object.onFailure (Auth.ts:2721:1)
    at CognitoUser.js:1517:1
    at Client.js:127:1
```

What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Device tracking is only supported for the `USER_SRP_AUTH` authentication flow - not the `CUSTOM_AUTH` flow that you're using.

As per [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-device-tracking.html#amazon-cognito-user-pools-setting-up-remembered-devices):

> You must use the `USER_SRP_AUTH` authentication flow to use the device tracking feature.

Technically, it is possible for AWS to extend device tracking to the `CUSTOM_AUTH` flow, especially to the custom flows that initiate SRP password verification. However, AWS currently doesn't provide this functionality for any other flow.

You need to implement this at an app level if required.

Comment: So in a solution with `CUSTOM_AUTH` there is no way to track a user device? Is there a workaround or something that others might have implemented to get over this hurdle? Since, we know that it is possible to track a device because it happens when we use `USER_SRP_AUTH` flow, why do they not expose it to `CUSTOM_AUTH` just the same way they have made `SRP_A` and `PASSWORD_VERIFIER` challenges available even in `CUSTOM_AUTH`.

Comment: @adNetDeveloper Updated the answer - why they don't expose it is up to the Cognito product team but it's not technically impossible. As regards to what others have implemented, a rough Google search doesn't bring up anything as it's going to be app specific.